# Issue in scraping data in bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, cmd, python-requests, replit

I want to scrape data from this website: "https://sephora.ae"
and I have written this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json



def sephora(URL):
    # opening our output file in append mode
    File = open("out.csv", "a")
    print("function start")
    # specifying user agent, You can use other user agents
    # available on the internet
    print(URL)
    HEADERS = ({'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)                  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)                     Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36', 
                           'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'}) 
 
    
    # Making the HTTP Request 
    webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)  
    
    # Creating the Soup Object containing all data 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')
    print("a")



    #brand name
    try:
        brand = soup.find_all('span', {"class": "brand-name"})
    except AttributeError:
        brand = 'NA'

    #Product Name
    try:
        prname = soup.find_all('meta', {"itemprop": "name"})["content"].text
    except AttributeError:
        prname = 'NA'

    #price
    try:
        price = soup.find_all('meta', {"itemprop": "price"})["content"].text
    except AttributeError:
        price = 'NA'

    #price currency
    try:
        price_cur = soup.find_all(
            'meta', {"itemprop": "priceCurrency"})["content"].text
    except AttributeError:
        price_cur = 'NA'

    #item code
    try:
        item_code = soup.find_all('meta', {"itemprop": "sku"})["content"].text
    except AttributeError:
        item_code = 'NA'

    #variant url
    try:
        urll = soup.find_all('meta', {"itemprop": "url"})["content"].text
    except AttributeError:
        urll = 'NA'

    #category
    try:
        category = soup.find_all('span', {"class": "product-name"}).text
    except AttributeError:
        category = 'NA'

    #size
    try:
        size = soup.find_all('img', {"class": "variation-image"})["alt"].text
    except AttributeError:
        size = 'NA'

    #image_src
    image_tags = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "variation-display-name"},
                               {"rel": "nofollow"})
    imagess = image_tags["data-lgimg"]
    res = json.loads(imagess)
    img_src = res['url']
    img_title = res['title']
    img_alt = res['alt']

    #description
    try:
        desc_div = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "product-description-box"})
    except AttributeError:
        desc_div = 'NA'
    
    # print(img_src)
    print(img_alt)
    # print(Item_code)
    # print(Size)
    File.write(f"{URL};")
    File.write(f"{brand};")
    File.write(f"{prname};")
    File.write(f"{category};")
    File.write(f"{urll};")
    File.write(f"{desc_div};")
    # File.write(f"{ingredients};")
    File.write(f"{price};")
    File.write(f"{price_cur};")
    File.write(f"{img_src};")
    File.write(f"{img_title};")
    File.write(f"{item_code};")
    File.write(f"{size}\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # opening our url file to access URLs
    print("start")
    file = open("url.txt", "r")
    header = "URL;BRAND;NAME;VARIANT LINK;DESCRIPTION;PRICE;PRICE CUR;IMG;TITLE;ITEMCODE;SIZE"
    File = open("out.csv", "w")
    File.write(f"{header}\n")
    File.close()

    URLs = file.readlines()
   
    for links in URLs:
        sephora(links)
    File.close()
```

but in out.csv, only the headers are coming and nothing else when I am running with repl.it.
And when I am running with cmd, then this error is coming

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sephora>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sephora\main.py", line 137, in <module>
    sephora(links)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sephora\main.py", line 33, in sephora
    prname = soup.find_all('meta', {"itemprop": "name"})["content"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue

I am using this URL for starting

https://www.sephora.ae/en/p/color-lip-last-lipstick-P1074023.html

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For first i think you need to change HEADERS type from tuple to dict:

```
HEADERS = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'}
```

then `soup.find_all('meta', {"itemprop": "name"})` return a list of elements

and you need change:

1. `prname = soup.find_all('meta', {"itemprop": "name"})["content"].text`

to
`prname = soup.find_all('meta', {"itemprop": "name"})[0].text`

2. `category = soup.find_all('span', {"class": "product-name"}).text`

to `category = soup.find_all('span', {"class": "product-name"})[0].text`

3. `size = soup.find_all('img', {"class": "variation-image"})["alt"].text`

to `size = soup.find_all('img', {"class": "variation-image"})[0]["alt"]`

and the like

docs: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#searching-the-tree

Comment: then also only headers are coming sir

Comment: I used the same sir. Can I share repl.it with you?? @RuslanZanevskiy

Comment: sorry but i didn't find a meta tag with any itemprop equals price name etc. I only find snap tag with class "price-sales price-sales-standard" and snap with class "product-name product-name-bold". may be you need to change this

Comment: in general, the problem is that this site does not load at all for me and I cannot check the code on my pc

Comment: thank you so much sir. please give me your repl.it username or email. So I can add you as a member @RuslanZanevskiy

Comment: RuslanZan - username

Comment: not coming sir, when I am typing RuslanZan

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused with a few of the concepts/methods with BeautifulSoup. Specifically grabbing attributes versus grabbing text/content. There's also the understanding the difference of `.find_all()` versus `.find()`. `.find_all()` will return a list of all those elements. So if you want a particular item form that list, you need to use the index. `.find()` will just return the first element it finds with the particular tag and attributes you are looking for.

Give this a try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json



def sephora(URL):
    # opening our output file in append mode
    File = open("out.csv", "a")
    print("function start")
    # specifying user agent, You can use other user agents
    # available on the internet
    print(URL)
    HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36', 
                           'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'}
 
    
    # Making the HTTP Request 
    webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)  
    
    # Creating the Soup Object containing all data 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')
    print("a")



    #brand name
    try:
        brand = soup.find('span', {"class": "brand-name"}).text
    except AttributeError:
        brand = 'NA'

    #Product Name
    try:
        prname = soup.find('meta', {"itemprop": "name"})["content"]
    except AttributeError:
        prname = 'NA'

    #price
    try:
        price = soup.find('meta', {"itemprop": "price"})["content"]
    except AttributeError:
        price = 'NA'

    #price currency
    try:
        price_cur = soup.find(
            'meta', {"itemprop": "priceCurrency"})["content"]
    except AttributeError:
        price_cur = 'NA'

    #item code
    try:
        item_code = soup.find('meta', {"itemprop": "sku"})["content"]
    except AttributeError:
        item_code = 'NA'

    #variant url
    try:
        urll = soup.find('meta', {"itemprop": "url"})["content"]
    except AttributeError:
        urll = 'NA'

    #category
    try:
        category = soup.find('span', {"class": "product-name"}).text
    except AttributeError:
        category = 'NA'

    #size
    try:
        size = soup.find('img', {"class": "variation-image"})["alt"]
    except AttributeError:
        size = 'NA'

    #image_src
    image_tags = soup.find("a", {"class": "variation-display-name"},
                               {"rel": "nofollow"})
    imagess = image_tags["data-lgimg"]
    res = json.loads(imagess)
    img_src = res['url']
    img_title = res['title']
    img_alt = res['alt']

    #description
    try:
        desc_div = soup.find('div', {"class": "product-description-box"}).text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        desc_div = 'NA'
    
    # print(img_src)
    print(img_alt)
    # print(Item_code)
    # print(Size)
    File.write(f"{URL};")
    File.write(f"{brand};")
    File.write(f"{prname};")
    File.write(f"{category};")
    File.write(f"{urll};")
    File.write(f"{desc_div};")
    # File.write(f"{ingredients};")
    File.write(f"{price};")
    File.write(f"{price_cur};")
    File.write(f"{img_src};")
    File.write(f"{img_title};")
    File.write(f"{item_code};")
    File.write(f"{size}\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # opening our url file to access URLs
    print("start")
    file = open("url.txt", "r")
    header = "URL;BRAND;NAME;VARIANT LINK;DESCRIPTION;PRICE;PRICE CUR;IMG;TITLE;ITEMCODE;SIZE"
    File = open("out.csv", "w")
    File.write(f"{header}\n")
    File.close()

    URLs = file.readlines()
   
    for links in URLs:
        sephora(links)
    File.close()
```

Comment: not working sir, even after following yours. Can you please help me on repl.it??

Comment: sure. my screename is the same as here

Comment: what's "not working"? Works fine on my end

Comment: can you please come on repl.it sir?? I will show you, no output is coming even in the console even after printing there.

Comment: `start
function start
https://www.sephora.ae/en/p/color-lip-last-lipstick-P1074023.html`

sir, only this much is coming

Comment: You can't run this in replit. This is a limitation with the platform (and understandable so). They don't currently allow outgoing network requests.

Comment: while using on cmd, problem is coming